# Cannot run React Native Project on Android Device or Simulator with React-Native-Maps dependency

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-maps

I am currently trying to build and run my project on android but it keeps failing. I followed all the instructions for setting up the android environment correctly, as I am able to get my other applications to work on the simulator. I am using the React native maps dependency on this project, and for some reason whenever I run `react-native run-android` it crashes with this error:
`error: constructor ActionSheetPackage in class ActionSheetPackage cannot be applied to given types;
            new ActionSheetPackage()
            ^
  required: FragmentActivity
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
1 error
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED`

Followed by:
`What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
 Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.`

I've tried troubleshooting using what can be found on the react-native-maps github page, and none of that seems to work. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Are you developing this in a clean project or do you have some existing codebase?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the issue was that there was a dependency that did not work on android. When I `npm install`ed the dependency it also installed it's self in the android portion of the project. Once I removed it from there it worked like a charm.